# The icremeant is not working like it should,to call another array with another values inside

Tags: javascript

I am making quiz application,where i want when the user click on some button,where the text inside is invalid answer for some question,will automatic go to another slide for the net question,that's the same for when the user clicks th right answer.In my code everything is working perfet when the user clicks just the right answers,but when he clicks wrong answer the incremeanting is confusing me,and i really dont know where is my mistake,it doesn't show the third question.

I update the whoel code,but the main problem occurs at the questionAndAnswers function at the if(where i am copmparing if the text inside the clicked button is not equal to the right answer) then icrement,and call the another array in the object with number 2 with that specific values"strings" inside,as i said with right answers works fine... please help 4 hours i am trying

```
const аrrayQandA = {

    question1 : ["Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript?"],
    questinAnswers1 : ["<js>" , "<javascript>" , "<script>" , "<scripting>"],
    questinCorrectAnswer1: ["<script>"],

    question2 : ["What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script called 'xxx.js'?"],
    questinAnswers2 :['<script src="xxx.js>"' , '<script href="xxx.js>"' , '<script name="xxx.js>"' , '<script id="xxx.js>"'],
    questinCorrectAnswer2 : ['<script src="xxx.js>"'],

    question3 : ["How do you write 'Hello World' in an alert box?"],
    questinAnswers3 :["alertBox('Hello World')" , "alert('Hello World')" , "msgBox('Hello World')" , "msg('Hello World')"],
    questinCorrectAnswer3 : ["alert('Hello World')"],

    question4 : ["  How do you create a function in JavaScript?"],
    questinAnswers4 :["function:myFunction()" , "function = myFunction()" , "function myFunction()" , "function myFunction() = function"],
    questinCorrectAnswer4 : ["function myFunction()"],

    question5 : ["How do you call a function named \"myFunction\"?"],
    questinAnswers5 :["myFunction()" , "call function myFunction()" , "function call myFunction()" , "call myFunction()"],
    questinCorrectAnswer5 : ["myFunction()"]
  }


function shuffle(array) {

    let counter = array.length;
    // While there are elements in the array
    while (counter > 0) {
        // Pick a random index
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

        // Decrease counter by 1
        counter--;

        // And swap the last element with it
        let temp = array[counter];
        array[counter] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

let allButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let replyToTheAnswer = document.querySelector(".replyToTheAnswer");
let quizSection = document.querySelector(".quizSection");
let questionSec = document.querySelector(".question");

let showingPoints = document.querySelector(".showingPoints");


let answersCounter = 1;

function making(answers) 
{
    shuffle(answers);
    console.log(answers);

    for(let i = 0; i < answers.length;i++) 
    {
        allButtons[i].innerText = answers[i];
    }

    questionAndAnswers(аrrayQandA[`question${answersCounter}`] , аrrayQandA[`questinAnswers${answersCounter}`],  аrrayQandA[`questinCorrectAnswer${answersCounter}`]);

}

making(аrrayQandA.questinAnswers1);


function questionAndAnswers(question , answers , correctAnswer) 
{
    questionSec.innerText = question;   

    console.log(answers);
    console.log(correctAnswer)
    console.log(correctAnswer.toString());

    correctAnswer = correctAnswer.toString();

    for(let i = 0;i < allButtons.length;i++)
    {
        allButtons[i].addEventListener("click" , function(event) 
        {
            console.log(event.target.innerText);

            if(event.target.innerText !== correctAnswer) 
            {
                replyToTheAnswer.innerText = "NOT CORRECT";
                answersCounter++;
                console.log(answersCounter);
                making(аrrayQandA[`questinAnswers${answersCounter}`]);
            }

            else if(event.target.innerText == correctAnswer) 
            {
                replyToTheAnswer.innerText = "CORRECT";
                answersCounter++;
                console.log(answersCounter);
                making(аrrayQandA[`questinAnswers${answersCounter}`]);
            }
        })
    } 
}
```

Comment: i've tried but no success :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the if-else with "!==" and "==", maybe none of the conditions is satisfying.

Try change to this more simple way:

```
if(event.target.innerText == correctAnswer) 
{
    replyToTheAnswer.innerText = "CORRECT";
}
else
{
    replyToTheAnswer.innerText = "NOT CORRECT";
}

answersCounter++;
console.log(answersCounter);
making(аrrayQandA[`questinAnswers${answersCounter}`]);
```

ternary version:

```
replyToTheAnswer.innerText = event.target.innerText == correctAnswer ? "CORRECT" : "NOT CORRECT";
```

Comment: Still the same,making problems with the increament